# Can compareAndSet fail for all threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, compare-and-swap, atomicinteger

I'm using `AtomicInteger` to compare and set synchronization state. Here is it

```
private final AtomicInteger state = new AtomicInteger(1);

public void tryDo(){
    if(state.compareAndSet(1, 2)){
        //do some usefule
    }
}
```

The question is if the following scenario possible:

1. `state = 1`
2. Two or more threads trying to `compareAndSet` the state to `2`
3. All the threads at `2.` fails and the state remains `1`

Is it documented? Is it platform dependent? How about `x86-64`?

Comment: all threads won't fail in my view. One thread should succeed always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the contract for [compareAndSet(int expect,int update)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet-int-int-):

> ... False return indicates that the actual value was not equal to the expected value.

So, by implication, if **only** these threads are accessing the value and you have confirmed that it **is** currently at `1` then the **ONLY** way for all to fail is if it was **NOT** at `1`. QED.

Comment: How about the contract of `lock cmpxchg`  on x86-64? __To simplify the interface to the processor’s bus, the destination operand receives a write cycle without regard to the result of the comparison. The destination operand is written back if the comparison fails__ It means we can read the written value for all threads, no? https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG.html

Comment: @SomeName - Then either there is more to the Java implementation of `compareAndSet` than just a `CMPXCHG`. i.e. one that ensures the documented contract is implemented - otherwise this is a bug (albeit a small one).

Answer (score 2):

threads can be broken by another cause... I not sure I've got your question properly...

I would say that it is not possible if there are no other causes,
just have a look on AtomicInteger impl:

```
    public final boolean compareAndSet(int expect, int update) {
        return unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(this, valueOffset, expect, update);
    }

    public final native boolean compareAndSwapInt(Object var1, long var2, int var4, int var5);
```